# How do I mount a shared VMWare folder on startup?

Tags: mount, vmware, fstab

So I'm following this article on [how to mount a shared vmware folder](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html).

I can successfully mount with the following command:

```
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/foo /home/user/Documents/foo
```

However, I can't seem to get it work with `/etc/fstab`.  I added this line:

```
.host:/foo /home/user/Documents/foo vmhgfs defaults 0 0
```

When I start up my machine, it prompts me to press <kbd>S</kbd> to skip mount or <kbd>M</kbd> for manual recovery and it won't mount.  I'm forced to press <kbd>S</kbd> to skip to get into the OS.  How can I fix this?

Edit: So I've found that VMware is already automatically mounting it to /mnt/hgfs/foo so my temporary workaround is a symlink to that directory. Is it possible to override this behavior so that I don't need a symlink?

Comment: I know it's a outrageously old question, but this solved my problem:
.host:/ /mnt/hgfs fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other 0 0 in the /etc/fstab and reboot the VM or system.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could put the mount command you use at the commandline in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I tried that, nothing happened.

Comment: If this works once you log in, and you don't need the mounted partition before that you could put something in your `.bashrc`. Doesn't explain though why it doesn't work as documented.

Comment: Added something new I found to the original question.